# Problem with the path of chromedriver using selenium with Google Collab on Windows

Tags: windows, selenium, path, webdriver

I installed selenium and chromedriver on Windows.

I copied chromedriver in */Windows/System32* under the name full path */Windows/System32/chromium-browser/chromedriver*.

Then I wrote :

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome("/Windows/System32/chromium-browser/chromedriver")
```

I also tried to write C: in front of /Windows, and I also tried to write r in front of "C:/..." and it did not solve the issue.

But I'm getting this error message :

> WebDriverException: Message: 'chromedriver' executable needs to be in PATH. Please see https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/home

I checked that I added chrome driver to the system variables :

[image]

PS: the error does not happen when I use a Jupyter Notebook instead of Google Collaboratory

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome("/Windows/System32/chromium-browser/chromedriver")
```

the windows chromedriver is a exe file so the above one is wrong you should be using somethign like

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="C:/Windows/System32/chromium-browser/chromedriver.exe")
```

make sure you have downloaded the correct version , and also use executable_path= argument name

Comment: The solution you provided looks good but you can't term OP's approach totally wrong. A couple of linux/windows/macos flavors still considers the default argument as the value for the _key_ `executable_path`.